# IllegalArgumentException Input == null

Tags: java, image, embedded-resource, javax.imageio, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to read an Image as an `InputStream`. But for some reason I always get an `IllegalArugmentException`.

Here is my code:

```
BufferedImage i = null; 
i = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/graphics" + path));
```

Comment: What does `"/res/graphics" + path` evaluate to ?

Comment: Can you make sure resource path accessible?

Comment: Are you sure your program able to read the file?

Comment: Try changing `getResourceAsStream` to `getResource`.  The way they evaluate paths is different.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The API docs says they are the same, and they both delegate to the ClassLoader.

Answer (score 2):

**Reason:**

Your resource evaluates to `null` and that is why the exception

[API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29)

> Throws:
>       IllegalArgumentException - if input is `null`.

**Solution:**

If `res/graphics/whatever` is in classpath at root then it will return not null

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the resource with the name does not exist. The resource is located by the class loader in the same way as a class with the name `res.graphics.whatever`, with of course a more relevant whatever. So just use the same methods to make a class accessible to make this resource accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Seems `"/res/graphics" + path` doesn't evaluate to your desired value.

Below is how you use `BufferedImage`,

```
public File myImg = new File("someImage.png");
BufferedImage in = ImageIO.read(myImg); 
//Just an example
BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(in.getWidth(), in.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

Comment: This is likely an [tag:embedded-resource].  A `File` won't work.