# Getting IllegalSrgumentException: input==null. When trying to load an image

Tags: graphics, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

i am trying to load an image to be used as a texture and i keep getting input==null errors; This is my code where i am trying to load the image and where most of the errors are pointing to.

```
package com.mime.minefront.graphics;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Texture {

public static Render floor = loadBitmap("/C:\\Users\\Danny\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MyFirstgame\\src\\res\\textures\\floor.png");
public static Render loadBitmap(String fileName) {
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Texture.class.getResource(fileName));
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        Render result = new Render(width, height);
        image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, result.pixels, 0, width);
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("CRASH!");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    }
}

}
```

and the errors i am getting are as followed.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.mime.minefront.graphics.Render3D.floor(Render3D.java:42)
at com.mime.minefront.graphics.Screen.render(Screen.java:28)
at com.mime.minefront.Display.render(Display.java:144)
at com.mime.minefront.Display.run(Display.java:112)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at com.mime.minefront.graphics.Texture.loadBitmap(Texture.java:19)
at com.mime.minefront.graphics.Texture.<clinit>(Texture.java:8)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
at com.mime.minefront.graphics.Texture.loadBitmap(Texture.java:11)
... 6 more
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [IllegalArgumentException Input == null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905496/illegalargumentexception-input-null)

Comment: `Texture.class.getResource(fileName)` returns `null` because you pass it an absolute path to a file, while you should pass it a path to the *resource* in class path. Probably `"/textures/floor.png"`.