# JAVA - JWJGL - IO Error: Input == Null

Tags: java, file-io, javax.imageio

I Keep Getting this when trying to load a texture from "/res/texBrick.png":

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at com.palo.verde.tut.lwjgl.basic.Main.loadTexture(Main.java:127)
at com.palo.verde.tut.lwjgl.basic.Main.initVar(Main.java:120)
at com.palo.verde.tut.lwjgl.basic.Main.run(Main.java:37)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is texture load code:

```
private int loadTexture(String string) {
    int tex;
    BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(Main.class.getResourceAsStream(string));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }

    int imgWidth = img.getWidth();
    int imgHeight = img.getHeight();

    // ...
}
```

This is really weird, considering in the video I was following it worked! Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `/res/texBrick.png` on the classpath?

Comment: @Sotirios Yes, it is :(

Comment: I don't believe you. Show us your setup and how you compile and run.

Comment: You sure you want the leading slash on the file path?

Comment: tried res/texBrick.png didn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [IllegalArgumentException Input == null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905496/illegalargumentexception-input-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I added the res folder as A class folder, so when I did /res/texBrick.png it didn't work because it's referneced as /texrBrick.png, Ah Me...