# Trying to set image icon for JLabel but URL returns null

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, javax.imageio

Trying to set image icon for `JLabel` but returns a `null` URL?

I am using Netbeans and have included background.png in my project but it still returns `null`?

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NewClass extends JFrame {

    JLabel o = new JLabel();

    public NewClass() {
        createImage("background.png");
        add(o);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(100, 100);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NewClass();
    }

    public void createImage(String str) {
        URL url = getClass().getResource(str);
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
            o.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Error details in stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
    at Test.NewClass.createImage(NewClass.java:32)
    at Test.NewClass.<init>(NewClass.java:18)
    at Test.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:26)
```

Please could you help unsure why it doesn't work, when i try

```
JLabel o = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("background.png");
```

It works but this is error prone incase background.png doesn't exist?
Thankyou

EDIT: components-SplitPaneDemo2Project - where this is name of netbeans project & background png is directly inside this folder

Located in here: 
 C:\Users\John\Documents\NetBeansProjects\components-SplitPaneDemo2Project

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Where is 'background.png' located? It seems 'background.png' couldn't be found.

Comment: What do you mean by "error prone"? This image file is part of your application. You can make sure that it exists.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html I was following this tutorial and they mentioned graceful error handling? I also trying to understand why this specific method doesn't work even if it is always part of the application - i have edited with where it is located

Comment: Given the String provided to `getResource(..)`, the JRE will expect to find the image in the same package as the class that loads it.  And by the above image, it sure doesn't look like it is in the right place..

Comment: There are [65 questions (roughly) asking the same](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bimageio%5D+input+%3D%3D+null) already. Why did you have to ask again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IllegalArgumentException Input == null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905496/illegalargumentexception-input-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested your code with some changes and it works fine:

```
public class NewClass extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    JLabel o = new JLabel();

    public NewClass() {
        initComponents();

        createImage("background.png");
        add(o);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(100, 100);
        setResizable(false);

        o.setLocation(20, 20);
        o.setSize(100, 25);
    }

    public void createImage(String str) {
        URL url = getClass().getResource(str);
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
            o.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
....
}
```

in the constructor I've set location and size for 'o'.

'background.png' must be in the parent package of 'NewClass'.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you are right I put it the src/test folder and then cleaned & built the project in netbeans. However, is there anyway i get it to look cleaner by putting it in a separate folder called pic in C:\Users\John\Documents\NetBeansProjects\components-SplitPaneDemo2Project\pic  and then somehow refer there instead of having messy images showing inside project package - Also when i was running on command line and had image and class in same folder it worked fine too?

Comment: Yes you can go this way, but by this, you'll use an absolute path to images which may cause the app depends on the file system. If you use images in your app package this problem never occur.

Comment: *"is there anyway i get it to look cleaner by putting it in a separate folder"*  That is frail and will fail on the next machine.  Put the image in the Jar.  It is the only sensible approach.  When you get more experienced, you might put all the images in a single Jar that is added to the run-time class-path of the main Jar, but stick with the simple way (as seen in this answer) for the immediate future.